# What is the Tensor Product of Set Rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, definition

Here are the definitions from my textbook:

A set ring on $\Omega$ is a family $\mathfrak{A}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ such that

1. $\emptyset \in \mathfrak{A}$
2. $A, B \in \mathfrak{A}$ implies $A - B, A \cup B \in \mathfrak{A}$

A set ring is a ring under the addition given by the symmetric difference $\Delta$ and the product given by set intersection $\cap$. Unless $\Omega \in \mathfrak{A}$, it is not a ring with 1.

The product ring $\mathfrak{A} \boxtimes \mathfrak{B}$ of two set rings $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ over $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ consists of the sets $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \times B_i $$
where $A_i \in \mathfrak{A}$, $B_i \in \mathfrak{B}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now the author says

> Those who know the tensor product from algebra will recognise $\mathfrak{A} \boxtimes \mathfrak{B}$ as the tensor product of the rings $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$.

Now I'm not very familiar with tensor products, but I thought that it involved a module structure, is this a tensor product in the sense that the set rings are viewed as modules over themselves? Or in the sense of some universal property?

Comment: A ring is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so you can consider $\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ which is the usual tensor product of abelian groups.

Comment: I should have thought of that, thank you @QuantumSpace !